# Is it true that synchronized blocks in java acquire the whole object lock?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

I know how synchronized methods in java work.

Suppose we have 3 synchronized methods in a class. If a Thread accesses 1 of the available methods, the other 2 get blocked for other threads.

If we change the synchronization implementation in 1 of methods to :

```
synchronized (this) {...}
```

Does it still work the same way and block the 2 other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does.

```
public synchronized void method() {...}
```

uses the object's instrinsic lock (`this`), so any other synchronized block using that lock:

```
synchronized(this) {...}
```

would block if the lock is already held.

Note: if a method is static, the picture is different, because the lock is not `this` any more, it is `YourObject.class`. In the example below, nothing prevents a thread T1 to run `method` while another thread T2 runs `someOtherMethod`, because the 2 sections don't use the same lock:

```
public static synchronized void method() {...}

public void someOtherMethod() {
    synchronized(this) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct .. in case of static, class level lock required.

Answer (score 2):

This is explained in the Java Tutorials section [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) (emphasis mine):

*When a thread invokes a synchronized method, **it automatically acquires the intrinsic lock for that method's object** and releases it when the method returns. The lock release occurs even if the return was caused by an uncaught exception.*

So, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The `synchronized` keyword, when applied to a method, is equivalent to wrapping the contents of the method in `synchronized(this)`.

The [spec says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6):

> A synchronized method acquires a monitor (§17.1) before it executes.
>
> For a class (static) method, the monitor associated with the Class object for the method's class is used.
>
> For an instance method, the monitor associated with this (the object for which the method was invoked) is used.